# Error while displaying data from SQLite3 using Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am creating an app for buying stocks using an API. The goal is to show a portfolio with the stocks bought displaying the current price. I have been working on the index function for days but I am constantly having errors. I would be grateful for any hints and help. Needless to say, I am a newbie and self-learner.
I having the following errors: File "/home/ubuntu/finance/helpers.py", line 34, in decorated_function
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/finance/application.py", line 57, in index
shares=stocks[0]["shares"]
KeyError: 'shares'

```
enter code here@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    user_id=session["user_id"]
    stocks= db.execute("SELECT symbol, sum(shares) as total_cost FROM stocks WHERE user_id=:user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=user_id)
    grand_total=0
    stocks_data=[]

    for stock_data in stocks:

        symbol=stocks[0]["symbol"]
        shares=stocks[0]["shares"]
        name=stocks[0]["name"]
        price=lookup(symbol)
        total_cost=shares*price["price"]
        grand_total+=total_cost
        stocks_data.append(stock_data)



    return render_template("index.html", stocks=stocks, stocks_data=stocks_data )
```

Html is here

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Symbol</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Shares</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Total Cost</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- TODO: Loop through the database to display all transactions and the balance -->
                        {% for stock_data in stocks_data %}
                           <tr>
                               <td>{{stock_data.symbol}}
                               <td>{{stock_data.name}}</td>
                               <td>{{stock_data.shares}}</td>
                               <td>{{(stock_data["price"])|usd}}</td>
                               <td>{{(stock_data["total_cost"])|usd}}</td>

                           </tr>

                        {% endfor %}
                           <tr>
                               <th>CASH</th>
                               <td>

                               </td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td>{{cash}}</td>


                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Grand Total</th>
                               <td>

                               </td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td>{{grand_total|usd}}</td>


                           </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(shares)` is aliased  to `total_cost` here `stocks= db.execute("SELECT symbol, sum(shares) as total_cost.....`. There is not key named `shares`; it is named `total_cost`.Either change the alias in the sql or change the key name here `shares=stocks[0]["shares"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed it to stocks= db.execute("SELECT symbol, name, sum(shares) as shares, price, total_cost FROM stocks WHERE user_id=:user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=user_id)

Comment: You're welcome. And for [your reading pleasure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)